# Node.js moongoose database count undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, model-view-controller, mongoose

I have the following function in one of my mongoose models:

```
UserSchema.methods.checkUsernameExists = function checkUsernameExists(req){
User.count({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, count){
    if(err){
        return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(count); //Logs 2
});
}
```

Now when I log it, it gives the correct count. But if I return the count and try doing this, in one of my controllers it returns undefined.

```
var User = require("../models/user").User;
var user = new User();

exports.signup = function(req, res){
    var count = user.checkUsernameExists(req);
    console.log(test)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Node works asynchronously, meaning that you can't return a normal value from a function that executes an asynchronous function itself, like your `checkUsernameExists` does.

The most common way to deal with this is by passing a callback function which is called when the value is retrieved:

```
UserSchema.methods.checkUsernameExists = function checkUsernameExists(req, callback) {
  User.count({ username: req.body.username }, callback);
};
```

This will pass the `err` and `count` variables that are the result of `User.count` as arguments to the callback function you supply. To use:

```
user.checkUsernameExists(req, function(err, count) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('the count is', count);
  }
});
```

To make the function to what it's name suggests, namely to 'return' a boolean to signify if a username already exists, you might use something like this:

```
UserSchema.methods.checkUsernameExists = function checkUsernameExists(req, callback) {
  User.count({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, count) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err);
    } else {
      callback(null, count !== 0);
    }
  });
};
```